# If current time is more than 30 seconds past time X (from the database)

Tags: php, time, if-statement

How would I construct a statement like if current time ($time) is more than 30 seconds past time (`$djs['currenttime']`)? Would it be something like

if (`$time => $djs['currenttime']`)? I can't figure it out with the 30 seconds..:).

Thanks :).

Comment: it would depend on the date format of variables. You could have a look at PHP function date_diff http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 30 seconds you are struggling with it's simply a `+30` added on the conditional incrementing the value of `$djs['currenttime']`.

You can use the `time()` function to get the actual time. I'm assuming that `djs['currenttime']` is a value extracted from the database. Therefore the comparison would be the following:

```
if(time() > $djs['currenttime'] + 30){
    //actions here;
}
```

`time()` returns the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970 00:00:00 GMT so for this to work, the format of the `$djs['currenttime']` variable should also be a unix timestamp. If not, you will need to convert one of them to the appropriate format first.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it is all based in seconds, not milliseconds or something smaller. Thankyou.

Comment: If you were using microtime instead of time, it would be using microseconds but time itself uses seconds as the unit.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($time > ($djs['currenttime'] + 30))
```

Assumes that both values are actual timestamps and not formatted strings